# Calculate the Limit of $f_n:= (\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n+\sqrt[n]{2n}-\frac{n^3}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n+\sqrt[n]{2n}-\frac{n^3}{2^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n+1-0$

Now, how to evaluate $(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n$?

Comment: Is it complex number $i$ there?

Comment: @Mathmore yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $||.||_2$  we will denote the complex absolute value.

We see that: $$||\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2}||_2=\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{25}{36}}=\frac{5}{6} <1$$

Thus $||\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2}||_2^n=(\frac{5}{6})^n \to 0$

Now we have that: $$||f_n-1||_2=||(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n+(\sqrt[n]{2n}-1)+\frac{n^3}{2^n}||_2 \leq ||\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2}||_2^n+|(\sqrt[n]{2n}-1)|+\frac{n^3}{2^n} \to 0$$

Thus $f_n \to 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2}|<1$, hence $(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i}{2})^n \to 0$.